# regex between two character positions with known start and end indices

Tags: javascript, regex, sed

In `regex`, generally speaking, is there a way to select data between two line positions? I'm not even sure the correct terminology (character/line position, index, column?) after a few days of reading up on `regex`, but what I mean is...

Select the data between two indices, what is between `^.{4}` and `^.{7}`, for example:

```
TESTINGREGEX
ISNTTHEBEST!
```

or

```
TESTINGREGEXCANBEFUN
ISNTTHEBEST!ANDFARFROMFUN
```

the results I'm looking for would be:

```
TESTREGEX
ISNTBEST!
```

and

```
TESTREGEXCANBEFUN
ISNTBEST!ANDFARFROMFUN
```

I'm wondering, so I can learn if it's possible, how to achieve it? I'm very familiar with other ways to do this using other tools, but I'm curious how to achieve this using `regex`.

I've tried working with non capturing groups, and wondering if maybe I'm being limited by the fact that I'm attempting to apply this regex within the `atom` editor find and replace `regex` feature (falling victim to: [Avoiding Common Pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)), so I'm hoping to get a few suggestions to broaden my knowledge and try out. I'm guessing `javascript`, and/or `sed` style `regex` answers would be acceptable...really anything would help!

EDIT:
`.{3}(?=.{5}$)` from [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121100/805031) works for me and with the example text I gave in the OP. And it's a good thing to know when able to count from the `$` end of line. But I'm realizing I actually need the opposite... I need to count out from the `^` start of line. Is this not possible; re: comments on there being no support for lookbehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just regex it's possible, just not in javascript.  The regex `(?<=^.{4}).+(?=.{5}$)` works to capture the group between the 4th letter and the 5th to last letter.  Since javascript doesn't support positive look behinds, you'll have to use some ammount of javascript beyond a simple `.replace(regex, "")` to remove those characters.

The next closest regex possible in javascript would be `.{3}(?=.{5}$)`, which would match 3 characters before the 5th to last letter.

If you wanted with pure regex in javascript to capture something a few characters after the start of a string it would be impossible.

Comment: `.{3}(?=.{5}$)` works for me! I'd actually tried exactly `(?<=^.{4}).+(?=.{5}$)` before as well during my research, but in `atom` at least I am getting "Invalid regular expression ...Invalid group", might search their issues list a bit more scrupulously and submit something. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @TryTryAgain Yeah, thats because although look behinds are officially part of the regex syntax, they just aren't supported by javascript for performance reasons (I assume).

Comment: @sweaver2112 does that mean the opposite of `.{3}(?=.{12}$)` wouldn't work? I'm realizing, from `$` end of line the count may change, I need to actually need to count from the left `^` start of line and match from nth character out from a set starting point.

Comment: Just clarifying that javascript has no "lookbehind", whether positive or negative. Only lookaheads (pos or neg).

Comment: @MarcGuiselin I updated the OP realizing the example I gave had a uniform end of line position, whereas my real use case that is not true. Wondering if the opposite is achievable?

Comment: The opposite of a positive lookahead (`(?=)`) is a positive look behind (`(?<=)`) which isn't supported by javascript.  so if you wanted with pure regex in javascript to capture something a few characters after the start it would be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `^(.{4}).{3}(.{5})$` (expressed in JavaScript's dialect, but the features used in it are quite common) will give you two capture groups you can combine to get the output you describe:

```js
function test(str) {
  var match = str.match(/^(.{4}).{3}(.{5})$/);
  console.log(str, '=>', match[1] + match[2]);
}
test("TESTINGREGEX");
test("ISNTTHEBEST!");
```

If the lines are of varying length and you want to ignore everything after the end of what you want, just drop the `$` assertion at the end.

Comment: But this is not flexible and will throw errors if the string is not 12 characters long (`"TEST"` will throw an error because nothing will be matched thus `match[2]` will be accessing the second item of undefined)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: See the note at the end about longer strings. Shorter ones, of course, don't make sense in terms of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to get the text between two character offsets then regular expressions are overkill. Just use `slice`:

```js
function exclude(str, i, j) {
    return str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(j);
}
console.log(exclude("TESTINGREGEX", 4, 7));
console.log(exclude("ISNTTHEBEST!", 4, 7));
```

If you really need to do this with regular expressions then proceed as follows:

```js
function exclude(str, i, j) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(`^(.{${i}})(.{${j-i}})`), "$1");
}
console.log(exclude("TESTINGREGEX", 4, 7));
console.log(exclude("ISNTTHEBEST!", 4, 7));
```